# My RecyclerView in ViewModel crashing app - kotlin android studio

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview, viewmodel

I have problem with RecyclerView into ViewModel.
RecyclerView without viewmodel working perfect.

My MainFragment:

```
private lateinit var shoppingListViewModel: ShoppingListViewModel
private lateinit var categoryAdapter: CategoryAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        shoppingListViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity())[ShoppingListViewModel::class.java]
    }

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.categoryRV.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        shoppingListViewModel.allCategories.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {   <-- when I add this line,
            updateCategories(it)                                                crashing my app
        })
    }


    private fun updateCategories(list: List<Category>) {
        categoryAdapter = CategoryAdapter(list)
        binding.categoryRV.adapter = categoryAdapter
    }
```

My ViewModel:

```
class ShoppingListViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val repository = Repository(application)
    val allCategories = repository.showAllCategories()
}
```

My Repo:

```
class Repository(app: Application) {
    private val shoppingListsDao = ShoppingListDatabaseBuilder.getInstance(app.applicationContext).shoppingListDao()

    fun showAllCategories(): LiveData<List<Category>> {
        return shoppingListsDao.showAllCategories()
    }
}
```

My Interface Dao:

```
@Dao
interface ShoppingListDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM category")
    fun showAllCategories(): LiveData<List<Category>>
}
```

Everything looks good, no errors. I don't know what going on :(

Answer (score 0):

I find my problem.

I need to update of version DB :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).